# How do I prevent LyX from loading inputenc?

Tags: lyx, packages, unicode, input-encodings

In my (out of the box) configuration of LyX, the line

```
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
```

is inserted in the generated .tex file by default. This makes it impossible for me to set different options (e.g., `utf8`) or to load other packages that are incompatible.

Is there a way to prevent LyX from loading `inputenc` with [latin9]?

Comment: Figured it out. Added [CW answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45099/7844).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Document > Settings...`, under `Language > Encoding`, choose "Other" and select "**Language Default (no inputenc)**". This will ensure that no

```
\usepackage[...]{inputenc}
```

line is added to the source:

[image: Screenshot of inputenc document settings in LyX]

Comment: So now, how do I change from latin9 (since I don't want this) to utf-8? (I do want that)

Comment: @user12711: That's a separate question.

Comment: @orome You can choose Unicode(utf8) from the dropdown menu