# How do I prevent LyX from using fontenc by default?

Tags: packages, lyx

All of the documents I create with LyX have

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble, which causes problems when I use certain classes or try to switch  from pdfLaTaX to XeTeX (for example).

Is there a way to prevent LyX from inserting this line in my documents?

Comment: LyX loads `fontenc`, because usually it is a good idea to use it (in combination with a `T1` font like `lmodern`): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc Do you have a special reason why you want to NOT load it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant settings are in app preferences under `Output > LaTeX`. Simply uncheck "Use LaTeX font encoding" and no `fontenc` line will be added:

[image: LyX UI for disabling inclusion of fontenc]

Comment: Ah, its not a document setting, but a global setting. This seems strange to be, but probably is better than nothing (but don't forget to switch it back on afterwards). Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: There's no need to label a self-answer as "Community Wiki": self-answers are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Playing it on the safe side.

Answer (score 7):

As the OP has already figured out, preventing the loading of any font-encoding package is only possible in the global preferences. Unfortunately, LyX misses a per-document setting for this.

However, if you check the "Use non-Tex fonts" option in the LyX document settings, LyX will load `fontspec` instead of `fontenc`. So switching to LuaTeX or XeTeX is easy and can be configured on a per-document base.

[image]

Comment: I [figured it out](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45335/7844) after some experimenting. This will indeed replace `fontenc` with `fontspec` [if checked](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45084/how-do-i-prevent-lyx-from-loading-inputenc), but if unchecked it will follow the app preference for LaTeX output and add `fontenc` if that's enabled. Both can in fact be disabled together (so, _no_ font-encoding related package gets loaded) if both are unchecked.