# Aalto custom CLS file in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, templates, document-classes, lyx-layouts

Oxford has instructions to set up CLS file for Lyx [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150887/using-a-new-document-class-template-with-lyx) so this thread for Aalto uni. So

**How can you use Aalto custom CLS file in Lyx?**

*Aalto files*

> - [CLS file](https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/69900685/aaltothesis.cls?version=1&modificationDate=1443108187586&api=v2) ([copy here](http://pastebin.com/xzzihHrj))
> - [Aalto Thesis LaTex template](https://wiki.aalto.fi/display/Aaltothesis/Aalto+Thesis+LaTeX+Template)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned similar quostion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150887/using-a-new-document-class-template-with-lyx). The CLS file uses the document class *Article*. It seems that easiest is to set up local `aaltothesis.layout` file for your thesis, not working yet: errors documented below. Other option is to put it under `/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/layouts/` but so far at least not working in my OSX Lyx.

The Aaltothesis.cls custom document class loads many options

> \documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,pdftex,elec,utf8]{aaltothesis}

where some of them such as inputenc are automatically loaded in Lyx: now need to find out how to load Custom Document Class in Lyx.

Under construction.

---

---

### **Steps in OS X**

---

1. Write your Lyx Layout for `article` according to the line `\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}%` in Aalto CLS file:

> `$ cd /; find . -iname "article.layout"`
>
> `./Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/layouts/article.layout`
>
> where we need to customise this layout by first changing the line *`\DeclareLaTeXClass{Article (Standard Class)}`* such that
>
> ```
> #% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
> #  \DeclareLaTeXClass[aaltothesis]{Aalto Math dept}
> #  \DeclareCategory{Articles}
> # Article textclass definition file. Taken from initial LyX source code
> # Author : Matthias Ettrich <ettrich@informatik.uni-tuebingen.de>
> # Transposed by Pascal André <andre@via.ecp.fr>
> # Heavily modifed and enhanced by serveral developers.
>
> Format 49 Input stdclass.inc
>
> SecNumDepth             3 TocDepth                3
>
> NoStyle Chapter NoCounter chapter NoStyle Chapter*
>
>
> Style Part
>     Align                 Left
>     AlignPossible         Left
>     TopSep                2
>     BottomSep             1.5
>     Font
>       Size                Larger
>     EndFont 
> End
>
>
> Style Part*
>     Align                 Left
>     AlignPossible         Left
>     TopSep                2
>     BottomSep             1.5
>     Font
>       Size                Larger
>     EndFont 
> End
> Provides inputec 1
> ```

2. Either use old aaltothesis.sty file with `\usepackage[sci]{aaltothesis}` such as [here](https://github.com/i-tu/Kandi/blob/master/aaltothesis.sty) or use the new Class file with `\documentclass[sci,parameters]{aaltothesis}` but the problem is that it is not totally straight-forward in Lyx.
3. ...

---

### TRIALS on the errors

*8th June: None of the trials working yet. My friend told me that the ELEC template is supposed to be used this way `\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,pdftex]{report} \usepackage[sci]{aaltothesis}` in preamble (see Trial 3). I am getting odd Inputenc err where loading things twice, cannot yet see what is causing this.*

---

**Trial 1 for the step 3 (that is not yet working, skipping it with local layout):** use local layout if LaTex cannot find the *.layout file

[image]

where move the `*.layout` file to your local dir

[image]

where getting new [errs](http://pastebin.com/6b8JvDpe) due to changing from Report document class to the Aaltothesis-article document class (not working yet).

**Trial 2** document with only text `testing aaltothesis.layout` and aaltothesis.cls in local dir and using the aaltothesis.layout as a local version

[image]

where getting [err](http://pastebin.com/GC50hEwt) that 'aaltologo.sty' not found *"LaTeX Error: File 'aaltologo.sty' not found."* so copy the `aaltologo.sty` from [here](https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/49383512/aaltologo.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1298143167000&api=v2) to your local directory.

[image]

where I have empty preamble and getting next errors.

**TRIAL 3** Premable with (**OLD:** aaltothesis.sty pkg has changed to CLS)

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,pdftex]{report} 
\usepackage[sci]{aaltothesis}
```

but err

[image]

such that

```
 \usepackage
               {amsmath}
The package inputenc has already been loaded with options:
  [utf8,]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [latin9]
Adding the global options:
  utf8,,latin9
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

where a peculiar amsmath err. I tried the change in `LyX: Document Settings > Math Options > Load automatically ALL to Do Not Load ALL` but same err

[image]

where this change did not alter the err. What is causing things to be loaded twice in LyX?

**TRIAL 4** Preamble with (**OLD:** aaltothesis.sty has changed to CLS)

> \usepackage[sci,utf8]{aaltothesis}

and comment out all lines to inputenc (Lyx loads Inputenc by default with latin9 by [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30221348#30221348))

[image]

where a mysterious file `aaltothesis.sty` missing, what is this? Only with `aaltothesis.layout` (generated), `aaltologo.sty`, `aaltothesis.cls` -- ideas, how/where to get this `aaltothesis.sty`?

**TRIAL 5 [BUG I discovered, patch below]** Empty preamble, trying to use aaltothesis.cls where `Class options` should be `sci` but I am getting peculiar `Missing number, treated as zero` with `sci` and without `sci`

[image]

where closer in logs (for reading logs in Lyx, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313780/runtime-logs-and-command-promth-in-lyx))

[image]

and now I am uncertain.

[image]

**TRIAL 6 with Patch I [BUG II uncovered]** First time compiled with only `hello world` but no macro working such as `\department{...}`

[image]

[image]

where Warning and Runaway argument around lines 164-171? Chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30238418#30238418). I tried different settings here such as `\value{page}`, `\thepage`, `\arabic{page}`, `\arabic{\value{page}}` but the same warning last -- no other error until this. Is this causing things to fail so not reading the next commands such as `\degreeprogram` correctly?

> [Update 2016 June 9th] **Mvim points out that lines 770-773 has some mismatched }, there are 2 pieces less } than { in aaltothesis.cls, chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30238559#30238559).**

Full log about the current error [here](http://pastebin.com/DtH9EfhM), **UNSOLVED**.

---

*Global setup (Unnecessary)*

1. Making files globally available Move the CLS file texmf folder to make it available `$ cp *.cls ~/Library/texmf/`  [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)
2. `Tools/Reconfigure` and restart Lyx and then `Document/Settings/Document Class` and pick up Aalto class [Error here, perhaps have to restart computer...?]

[image]

---

### **Setup**

---

1. [aaltothesis.layout](http://pastebin.com/az3mNLhL) (remix from standard article article.layout) where name change to `aaltothesis` layout from article and `Provides inputenc 1` on the last line addition
2. [aaltothesis.cls](https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/69900685/aaltothesis.cls?version=1&modificationDate=1443108187586&api=v2) (where article used so hence article.layout chosen as default, right?) and [copy here](http://pastebin.com/xzzihHrj) if the link expires about the aaltothesis.cls
3. [aaltologo.sty](https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/49383512/aaltologo.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1298143167000&api=v2) and its landing directory [here](https://wiki.aalto.fi/display/aaltolatex/Aalto+University+logo+package)

**TIPS**

1. for fast debugging: `Lyx > Document Settings > Local Layout`

[image]

---

### BUGS in Aaltothesis.cls

---

I. [*"the class sets the counter to \thepage, this is a fault in the class --\thepage can be text and so shouldn't be used to set counters."*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30224122#30224122)

> **Solution by David** [`use \value{page} not \thepage`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30224330#30224330)

II. TRIAL 6 uncovered mysterious `Runaway argument` warning and we found out that the `aaltothesis.cls` file has 2 curly brackets more than opening brackets. The runaway arguments starts near the first bug of `\thepage` instead of `\value{page}`

Comment: Thanks, keep us informed of your progress. Comments: 1) You can put everything: cls file, layout file and sty files, in the same directory as your lyx file (use choose local layout file). The question of installing them system-wide is unnecessary at first (you can try Reconfigure to get rid of your "Unavailable" problem). 2) I recommend writing the layout inside the tab Document Preference>Local layout, for a better trial-and-error cycle (apart from the first lines with \DeclareLaTeXClass, that must be in the layout file).

Comment: 4) The file thesistemplate.tex shows you what you want to obtain. It is not `\usepackage...{aaltothesis}` but `\documentclass...{aaltothesis}`. I don't think there is a aaltothesis.sty file. 5) The cls file contains `\LoadClass{article}` and therefore you should start by copying article.layout. 6) The beginning of your layout file must be `#\DeclareLaTeXClass[aaltothesis]{Aalto Thesis}`

Comment: 7) for any error `The package xyz has already been loaded with options`, you can try to add in the layout file: `Provides xyz 1` (but first try to change document options in lyx so that the options match, to avoid bad surprises later)

Comment: @G.M. this CLS loads many options such as `\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,pdftex,elec,utf8]{aaltothesis}` where some such as inputenc>latin9 are automatically loaded by LyX. Is this a problem? Other options such as ELEC are defined in the class.

Comment: In this case I recommend to: 1) add `Provides inputenc 1`. This disables loading of `inputenc` by lyx. 2) Set Language > Encoding to utf8 so that there is no mismatch between the class and lyx. 3) To pass the option ELEC you can add it under document class options.

Comment: @G.M. 1) `Provides inputec 1` on which line or by this `Lyx: Document Settings>Language > Other > Language Default (no inputenc)` [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45099/2956)? 2) I cannot find `Language > Encoding` in OSX Lyx. 3) In my Lyx, I have `Lyx: Document Settings > Document Class > Class options > Custom`, is this the correct place?

Comment: 1) `Provides inputenc 1` at the end of the layout file, or in this case the setting you mention should work 2) Under Document Settings. 3) Yes.

Comment: The first step consists in *changing a file in the application bundle*! Are you *really* meaning it? An update to LyX will destroy your so patiently built setup.

Comment: Let me clarify. We are working on a _copy_ of article.layout, placed in the user's directory. In addition I have suggested to first test changes in Document > Local layout. So the line either has to be added to the new layout file, or temporarily to the local layout.

Comment: @G.M. by the line, you mean this [here](http://pastebin.com/UgBey4hr), picture [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DoXyG.png) in the `Document > Local Layout` settings? With `Provides inputec 1` just catenated to the end of the `aaltothesis.layout`?

Comment: This looks correct. And you should do the same for any other package loaded by the cls file. Note that it is useless to replicate everything in the local layout, this is just for trying quickly before writing to the layout file. It would be nice if once everything works you clean-up a bit your answer by keeping the correct steps, so that others can follow the procedure.

Comment: @G.M. I updated everything to correspond to the newest additions, also the Bug number II `Runaway argument` warning that I suspect to cause all macros not to work in `aaltothesis.cls` file, for some reason LyX does not tolerate the buggy class file, ideas why?