# Runtime logs and command prompt in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, debugging

LyX is a GUI based editor. The ability to see which LaTeX things are loaded each time would be useful. Example is [Trial 5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313511/2956) where I try to determine whether Lyx loaded the aaltothesis.cls correctly. So

**Is there any command prompt or runtime logs available in LyX?**

Comment: Document --> LaTeX Log?

Comment: Also, if you're just interested in the source, View --> Source pane, and select *Complete source*.

Comment: I agree with Torbjørn T. Note that if you leave the source pane open while you edit, LyX might be slow because it will be continuously exporting the entire document to LaTeX.

Comment: For more information, you can also do View > Messages Pane. You can select whether you want very verbose logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

- If you wish to see the actual LaTeX source that LyX generates, select **View --> Source Pane**. In the panel that appears, there is a box on the right where you can choose *Complete source*. (The default might be *Current paragraph*.)
- If you want to see the `.log` file from (`pdf`|`xe`|`lua`)`latex`, go to **Document --> LaTeX log**.
- For even more information, **View --> Messages Pane**.