# Installing Lyx2.3.2 on ubuntu

Tags: xetex, lyx, miktex

I'm trying to install lyx 2.3.2 on ubuntu 18.10, so I installed miktex and donwloaded a lyx2.3.2 source file from the official site and builded it using cmake I maneged to exucte the app but only using ./lyx2.3 on terminal and not as free app, and after traing to compile a pdf file I get this messege:

```
The external program xelatex finished with an error. It is recommended you fix the cause of the external program's error (check the logs).
```

Can someone help me?
PS: I'm new on ubuntu.

Comment: The message suggests that you check the logs, so that would be a good place to start. You can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313780/runtime-logs-and-command-prompt-in-lyx for some directions for the GUI. From the terminal you can look at the most recent file with the extension `.log` in the folder where you tried to compile, for example if your file is called `myfile.tex` then the log file is `myfile.log` and you can see it with `less myfile.log`. If there is anything in the log you don't understand you can ask about it here (after searching for similar errors of course).

Comment: My guess is that LyX has not been tested much at all with MiKTeX + Linux. Usually on Linux TeX Live is used. Can you compile .tex files outside of LyX? i.e., on the command line? Instead of usine xetex, does a simple document compile in LyX with pdflatex?