# How to view runtime Latex logs in TextMate?

Tags: debugging, textmate

In order to understand what is going on underneath, I want to find the runtime logs in TextMate, debugging [this](https://wiki.aalto.fi/display/Aaltothesis/Aalto+Thesis+LaTeX+Template) and now from [Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313510/aalto-custom-cls-file-in-lyx) to TextMate but buggy class.

**Where can you find runtime logs in TextMate while typesetting LaTex?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the link to `untitled.log` to open the logfile inside TextMate:

[image: TextMate Log Window]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a parsed version of the log: TextMate filters only warnings and errors from the log but hides all of the other stuff. If you want to view the whole log file, you just need to open untitled.log in your example. The file name will be [file name of main tex file].log, i. e. instead of .tex its file extension is .log.)

Comment: And with shortcut easier `CTRL+o Untitled.log`, unbelievable that no other builtin solution because logs are so important. Thank you.