# LyX + BibLaTeX handling non ASCII UTF-8

Tags: biblatex, lyx, utf8

Sorry to repeat this question, but I have gone through several similar questions asked in the past without success. I am using LyX Version 2.3.6.1 with this document

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine biblatex
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblatex_bibstyle authoryear
\biblatex_citestyle authoryear
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
MWE
\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand cite
key "bruning_lhc_2004"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
btprint "btPrintCited"
bibfiles "mwe"
options "plain"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

and I have this `mwe.bib` file

```
@misc{bruning_lhc_2004,
    title = {{LHC} Design Report Volume 1 The {LHC} Main Ring},
    url = {https://cds.cern.ch/record/782076},
    abstract = {The {LHC} Design Report is presented in three volumes: the first concerns the main ring, the second the infrastructure and general services and the third, the injector chain. The conceptual design was published in 1995 and this report provides a snapshot of the detailed design as it stands at the time of writing - early 2004.},
    author = {Brüning, Oliver Sim and Collier, Paul and Lebrun and Myers, Stephen and Ostojic, Ranko and Poole, John and Proudlock, Paul},
    urldate = {2022-06-13},
    date = {2004},
    langid = {english},
    doi = {10.5170/CERN-2004-003-V-1},
    note = {{ISBN}: 9789290832249
Number: {CERN}-2004-003-V-1
Publisher: {CERN}},
    file = {Snapshot:/home/alf/Zotero/storage/WVBXWPF3/782076.html:text/html}
}
```

It is failing to process characters like the `ü` in the name of the authors:

[image]

I don't want to go through the solution of replacing each non ASCII character by some weird escape sequence, so I moved from BibTex to BibLaTeX, which I read was able to handle this. However, it still fails. Is it possible to tell LyX/LaTeX/whoever to appropriately process non ASCII characters in the bibliography?

In case it helps, if I export the LaTeX code from LyX, it produces this

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
MWE~\cite{bruning_lhc_2004}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post some (La)TeX code: Few people here use Lyx, its internal data format is not useful to the rest of us.

Comment: Your files need to be in UTF-8 (Unicode) formatting. Get rid of `inputenc`.

Comment: Make sure LyX is set up to produce Unicode output, not `latin9`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45084/35864. See also https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Unicode

Comment: Also you need to tell LyX to user `biber` not `bibtex` to process the bibliography. See https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Comment: Getting rid of `inputenc` solved the problem. @Ingmar if you want to upgrade your comment to answer I can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BibLaTeX` can work with accented characters, but your input must be in Unicode (utf-8) throughout. This has been the default for modern TeX engines for some time anyway. You're currently using ISO Latin-8859-15:

```
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
```

Get rid of that line (using the default utf-8).